# prop.table with filter condition

Tags: r, proportions

For the mtcars dataset I want to find out how many cars with 1, 2, 3 etc. carbs have either 4, 6 or 8 cylinders.

I therefore used `prop.table()`

`prop.table(with(mtcars, table(carb, cyl)), margin = 1)`

which results in:

```
    cyl
carb         4         6         8
   1 0.7142857 0.2857143 0.0000000
   2 0.6000000 0.0000000 0.4000000
   3 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
   4 0.0000000 0.4000000 0.6000000
   6 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
   8 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
```

I want to do the same now only with a filter condition. I only want to count those cars with gear == 4. I tried to use an if statement but it didn't work (*error message:*  *the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*)

Edit: I still want to put those cars with gear == 4 into perspective with the overall number of cars. So deleteing those cases who do not match the gear == 4 criteria beforehand is unfortunately not purposeful in my case.

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  filter(gear == 4) %>% 
  {prop.table(table(carb = .$carb, cyl = .$cyl), margin = 1)}

#>     cyl
#> carb 4 6
#>    1 1 0
#>    2 1 0
#>    4 0 1
```

Comment: I still want to put those cars with gear == 4 into perspective with the overall number of cars. So deleteing those cases who do not match the gear == 4 criteria beforehand is unfortunately not purposeful in my case.

Comment: What would then be your expected output, @Sascha?